# Grid's background setting affect text in it, what should I do to keep text without background?

Tags: graphics, grid-layouts

I use this command

```
Grid[{
  {1, 2},
  {Graphics[{Blue, Disk[], Text[Style["1", Large, Red]]}],
   Graphics[{Blue, Disk[], Text[Style["2", Large, Red]]}]}
  }, Background -> LightGray]
```

[image]

But I don't want grid's background setting to affect the number in graphics, like the graphics blow. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: this issue seems to be version/os related. It does not arise in version 12.0 (Wolfram Cloud). Which version/os are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifying `Background -> None` at the right place in the `Graphics` body works in version 10.1:

```
Grid[{{1, 2}, 
  Graphics[{Blue, Disk[], Background -> None, 
      Text[Style[#, Large, Red]]}] & /@ {"1", "2"}}, Background -> LightGray]
```

[image]

Comment: I put "Background -> None" in the end of Graphics and in Text won't work. Can I ask why put "Background -> None" in the middle solve my problem in the most easy way? Thank you very much.

Comment: @pmzhu In the manner I used it `Background -> None` needs to come before the `Text` expressions, just like `Blue` needs to come before `Disk[]`.  You could also use the more specific `{Background -> None, Text[. . .]}` should this conflict with some other part of the graphics.

Comment: That is a very clear explanation, now I understand why. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Maybe this will be a solution:

diskTable[colDisk_: Blue, colText_: Red, colBack_: LightGray, 
   sizeDisk_Integer: 250, textSize_Integer: 24, numDisk_Integer: 2] :=
   Block[{i = 1}, 
   Row[Table[
     Column[{Style[i, textSize - 10, colText], 
       Graphics[{colDisk, Disk[], 
         Text[Style[i++, textSize, colText]]}, 
        ImageSize -> sizeDisk]}, Alignment -> Center], numDisk], 
    Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> colBack, Background -> colBack]];

diskTable[]
```